# Setting browser zoom via viewport or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, viewport

Is there any way to change the default zoom of a browser with viewport or javascript,when users acces your website?(PC,Laptops)

Answer (score 0):

Ohh ive seen you mean PC, Laptops
That is only possible via css (or javascript css manipulation) you should set a zoom attribute to the body element 
even though i don't recommend to do this its the only way I know

OLD POST:
You should give this site a try:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

especialy this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The initial scale is like a zoom for your page

Comment: and for example,if i want the zoom to be set at 90% ? or 110%? what value should initial-scale have?

Comment: initial scale is unfortunately just for mobile devices. Means you cant scale your webpage with that for desktop. But if you want this for mobile devices use 0.9 as 90% and 1.1 as 110%.

For the zoom attribute: you can use % numbers there

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

where `initial-scale` is what you want, you also might want to change `user-scaleble` to `yes` depending on system requirements.

Comment: and for example,if i want the zoom to be set at 90% ? or 110%? what value should initial-scale have?